# regex match fewest words between two words when the first word is present twice before the last word globaly

Tags: php, regex

**I have this Content:**

3014/2010 FREE STATE HIGH COURT, BLOEMFONTEIN (Republic of South Africa) In the matter between: FIRSTRAND BANK LIMITED, Plaintiff, and ANDREA MAXWELL MOSES TOBIAS (ID No. 7111175172087), 1st Defendant, and JENNEFER THERESA TOBIAS (ID No. 6803070035085), 2nd Defendant NOTICE OF SALE In pursuance of a judgment in the Free State High Court, Bloemfontein, Republic of South Africa, dated 9 July 2010 and a warrant for execution against immovable property, the following property of the Defendants will be sold in execution by public auction on Wednesday, 23 October 2013 at 10:00, held at the premises of Sheriff west, 6A Third Street, Arboretum, Bloemfontein, to the highest bidder, namely: Property description: Certain: Erf 3354, Ashbury, Extension 7, District Bloemontein, Free State Province and better known as 15 Hillcrest Street, Ashbury, Bloemfontein, Free State province, measuring 496 (four nine six) square metres, held by Deed of Transfer No. T20116/1995. The property is zoned: Residential. A residential dwelling consisting of: Lounge, kitchen, 3 x bedrooms, 1 x shower, 1 x toilet, 4 x garages. (The nature, extent, condition and existence of the improvements are not guaranteed and are sold ?voestoots?). Additions: None. The conditions of sale will be read prior to the sale in execution by the Sheriff and may be inspected at the Sheriff-East Offices, with address 3 Seventh Street, Arboretum, Bloemfontein, and/or at the offices of the Attorney of Plaintiff, Messrs Symington & De Kok, 169B Nelson Mandela Drive, Bloemfontein. Take further notice that: This is a sale in execution pursuant to a judgment obtained in the above Court. Rules of this auction are available 24 hours foregoing the sale at the offices of the Sheriff, East, 3 Seventh Street, Arboretum, Bloemfontein. Registration as a buyer, subject to certain conditions, is required i.e. 3.1 Directions of the Consumer Protection Act 68 of 2008 (URL http://www.info.gov.za/view/DownloadFileAction?id=99961) 3.2 Fica-legislation i.r.o. identity & address particulars. 3.3 Payment of registration monies. 3.4 Registration conditions. The sale in execution will be held at the offices of the Sheriff West, with address 5 Barnes Street, Westdene, Bloemfontein, and will be conducted by auctioneers P Roodt and A J Kruger. Advertising costs at current publication tariffs & sale costs according Court Rules will apply. Sonette Oosthuizen, Attorney for Plaintiff, Symington & De Kok, Symington & De Kok Building, 169B Nelson Mandela Drive, Bloemfontein. Tel: (051) 505-6727. (Ref: MT1089/carol.) Sheriff, Bloemfontein East. Tel: (051) 447-3784. STAATSKOERANT, 11 OKTOBER 2013 No. 36907 151  VEILING

**I have this Regex pattern:**
/(?i)sheriff(.*?)\bEast\b/g

**I get this result:**

MATCH 1
 1. [610-1355]  `west, 6A Third Street, Arboretum, Bloemfontein, to the highest bidder, namely: Property description: Certain: Erf 3354, Ashbury, Extension 7, District Bloemontein, Free State Province and better known as 15 Hillcrest Street, Ashbury, Bloemfontein, Free State province, measuring 496 (four nine six) square metres, held by Deed of Transfer No. T20116/1995. The property is zoned: Residential. A residential dwelling consisting of: Lounge, kitchen, 3 x bedrooms, 1 x shower, 1 x toilet, 4 x garages. (The nature, extent, condition and existence of the improvements are not guaranteed and are sold ?voestoots?). Additions: None. The conditions of sale will be read prior to the sale in execution by the Sheriff and may be inspected at the Sheriff-`

MATCH 2
 2. [1744-1746] `,`

MATCH 3
1.  [2176-2592] `West, with address 5 Barnes Street, Westdene, Bloemfontein, and will be conducted by auctioneers P Roodt and A J Kruger. Advertising costs at current publication tariffs & sale costs according Court Rules will apply. Sonette Oosthuizen, Attorney for Plaintiff, Symington & De Kok, Symington & De Kok Building, 169B Nelson Mandela Drive, Bloemfontein. Tel: (051) 505-6727. (Ref: MT1089/carol.) Sheriff, Bloemfontein`

**The result I want:**

MATCH 1
 1. [610-1355]  `-`

MATCH 2
 2. [1744-1746] `,`

MATCH 3
1.  [2176-2592] `, Bloemfontein`

The pattern matches the first "sheriff" and then the first "east" however there is another "sheriff" in between the two. I want it to match closest two words(the second "sheriff" and first "east"). It also needs to be global.

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sheriff((?:(?!sheriff).)*?)\bEast\b
```

Try this.This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lE9oV4/3

Comment: @Jonny5 not very easy......you are not slowing down....